# There was an error parsing the query SQL Server CE / VS 2010 local database

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I wrote an little app in C# to keep track of customers and jobs but I get an error

> "There was an error parsing the query.[Token line number = 1, Token
>   line offset = 38,Token in error = Name]

I'm using a SQL Server CE `.sdf` database

```
    public static List<string> ListDates(string clientname)
    {
        List<string> date = new List<string>();
        string myName = clientname;
        using (SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM FarmJobs WHERE Name = ?Name;";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", myName);
            SqlCeDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    date.Add(Reader["DateSeviceStarted"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        return date;
    }
```

I researched the error a lot and seems this error is pretty vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used a '`?`' where you needed a '`@` for the `Name` parameter:

```
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FarmJobs WHERE Name = @Name"; 
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", myName);
```

[***Side note***: I would recommend using an explicit column list rather than `SELECT *` ]